# Targeting the correct item to style with Material-UI JSS and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss, mui

I'm new to Material-UI, and fairly new to React and web development. I'm trying to understand how to work with Theme, createStyles, and JSS within the MUI framework.

I grabbed the code for a responsive component directly from the documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/#mini-variant-drawer). With the styles at the top of the file, the component works as expected. However, when I try to target the icons to change the color nothing is rendering the color I chose.

**Here is the JSS in a separate file:**
This file is called: .src/shared/components/AppFrame/styles.js

```js
import { createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';


const drawerWidth = 240;

export const styles = (theme) => createStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 36,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    color: 'white',
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    paddingTop: 64,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
  color: theme.palette.common.white,
  width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    paddingBottom: 64,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
  color: theme.palette.common.white,
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 7 + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9 + 1,
    },
  },
  topToolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    margin: '24px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
  listItem: {
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  icon: {
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  }
});
```

**The component file looks like this:**
.src/shared/components/AppFrame/index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Drawer, AppBar, Toolbar,
  List, Typography, Divider, IconButton,
  ListItemText, ListItemIcon, ListItem,
  CssBaseline
} from '@material-ui/core';

import {
  Menu as MenuIcon,
  ChevronLeft as ChevronLeftIcon,
  ChevronRight as ChevronRightIcon,
  Inbox as InboxIcon
} from '@material-ui/icons';

import {
  Group as GroupIcon,
  Apps as AppsIcon
} from '@material-ui/icons'

import { styles } from './styles'

class MiniDrawer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
  }

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: this.state.open,
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open}>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Open drawer"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
              className={ classNames(classes.menuButton, {
                [classes.hide]: this.state.open,
              }, classes.icon )}
            >
              <MenuIcon className={classes.icon} />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
              Evolv
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          className={classNames(classes.drawer, {
            [classes.drawerOpen]: this.state.open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !this.state.open,
          })}
          classes={{
            paper: classNames({
              [classes.drawerOpen]: this.state.open,
              [classes.drawerClose]: !this.state.open,
            }),
          }}
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          <div className={classes.toolbar}>
            <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose} classes={classes.icon}>
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <GroupIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <GroupIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Typography paragraph>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
            consequat mauris.
          </Typography>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MiniDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MiniDrawer);
```

**Here is a screenshot of the current state:**
[image]

The issue is that I am trying to get the icons and text in the sideDrawer to appear white. Any tips, advice, or resources to better understand how the styling works with MUI is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error in your console doesn't seem to match up with the code in your question. A CodeSandbox reproducing your problem would be helpful. You can either [create one from scratch](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) or use the [Mini variant drawer demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7joy724pl) as a starting point.

Comment: That was a great tip, thanks. I was able to target the item by adding an icon property to the styles object. 

```icon: color: theme.palette.common.white, ```

Then I applied it in the  
```<ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}> ```
and 
```<ListItemText
                  primary={text}
                  classes={{primary: classes.icon}}
                />
```